# Formulating ordinary problems mathematically in order to solve them

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, word-problem

I've been thinking about an ordinary problem for which there doesn't seem
to exist a solution given its constraints. I was wondering how would one
go about formulating the problem mathematically such that the
non-existence of the solution can be proven.

*An example:*

4 flatmates **{1,2,3,4}** are deciding on how to distribute 4
housekeeping tasks: garbage disposal (**G**), grocery shopping (**S**),
big bathroom cleaning (**B<sub>1</sub>**), small bathroom cleaning
(**B<sub>2</sub>**).

The conditions are (weeks should be understood as 7 days, not calendar weeks):

1) Tasks G, B2, and S must be completed every week.

2) Task B1 must be completed twice within every week, but not on the same day.

3) Tasks B1 and B2 are completed simultaneously by one flatmate once a week in order to reduce overhead.

4) Each flatmate must complete each task at least once.

5) Flatmates 1, 2, and 3 can complete tasks on Monday and Thursday.

6) Flatmate 4 can only complete tasks on Monday.

Questions:

- Is it possible to divide the housekeeping such that over the course of
  4 weeks all flatmates complete the exact same number of tasks?
- If not, what distribution of tasks meets the conditions and minimizes
  the total number of tasks over the course of 4 weeks?
- How would the generalization of this problem (and its solution) look
  like if there are **n** flatmates, **m** tasks, and **not only**
  flatmate 4 has a time constraint?

Comment: how much time does each task need to be completed?

Comment: Do the two cleanings of the big bathroom have to be on different days? If not, then I'd volunteer to clean it immediately after you've thoroughly cleaned it. (The point is that you probably have more assumptions than you've explicitly stated.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass haha very good point. Yeah, some real world assumptions are in there (adjusted accordingly, thx!).

Comment: @dcolazin assume an hour